# Invalid Pointer Operation -- don't know why

Tags: delphi

I have been struggling with a problem and developed a sample application that shows (more or less -- error happens, but it's at a different spot) the issue I've been having.

The idea of this code is to have an object TGenericList that contains a list of generic objects that hold different types of data (e.g. Integer, Double, Records, etc).  When one of the objects changes, it should notify the list that is holding the object.

The sample program, when run, gives me an EInvalidPointer exception at the line

```
L.Free;
```

at the end of the application.

When tracing in the debugger the exception is raised in a TInterfacedObject routine:

```
procedure TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if RefCount <> 0 then
    Error(reInvalidPtr);
end;
```

What I see is that Destroy is called and then System._BeforeDestruction() is called:

```
function _BeforeDestruction(const Instance: TObject; OuterMost: ShortInt): TObject;
// Must preserve DL on return!
asm //StackAlignSafe
       { ->  EAX  = pointer to instance }
       {      DL  = dealloc flag        }
       { <-  EAX  = pointer to instance }  //  Result := Instance;
        TEST    DL,DL
        JG      @@outerMost                //  if OuterMost > 0 then Exit;
        RET
@@outerMost:
{$IFDEF ALIGN_STACK}
        PUSH    ECX     // 4 byte adjustment, and ECX is convenient
{$ENDIF ALIGN_STACK}
        PUSH    EAX
        PUSH    EDX
        MOV     EDX,[EAX]                  //  Instance.BeforeDestruction;
        CALL    DWORD PTR [EDX] + VMTOFFSET TObject.BeforeDestruction
        POP     EDX
        POP     EAX
{$IFDEF ALIGN_STACK}
        POP     ECX     // 4 byte adjustment, and ECX is convenient
{$ENDIF ALIGN_STACK}
end;
{$ENDIF X86ASMRTL}
```

The exception occurs at the call to TObject.BeforeDestruction.

If I delete the line

```
ABase.RegisterObserver(Self);
```

in TGenericList.AddBase(), I don't get the exception.  Also note that I haven't even implemented the change notification method so the list of observers is never really used -- it just exists and holds object references.  In this case, one.

The only thing I can think of is that the TList is somehow freeing the observers and therefore when I call L.Free, it is already free'd.  I didn't think TList does that.  The help file says that TObjectList does.  Then again, it never seems to get to the line where the list is free'd which would free the TBase objects.

I get no warnings when I compile.

I am running Delphi - Tokyo (10.2), Community Edition.

```
program GenericTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  IObserver = interface
    ['{DD9243B9-0722-486A-B4BF-0929AB5B6627}']
    procedure ObservableChanged(Sender : TObject);
  end;

  IObservable = interface
    ['{39EA6448-6636-40F4-B618-740B0BB28127}']
    procedure RegisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
    procedure UnregisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
  end;

  TBase = class(TInterfacedObject, IObservable)
  private
    FName : String;
    FObservers : TList<IObserver>;
  public
    constructor Create(AName : String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure RegisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
    procedure UnregisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
    property Name : String read FName;
  end;

  TGenericBase = TBase;

  TGenericBase<T> = class(TGenericBase)
  private
    FData : T;
  public
    constructor Create(AName : String);
    constructor CreateValue(AName : String; AValue : T);
    property Data : T read FData write FData;
  end;

  TGenericList = class(TInterfacedObject, IObserver)
  private
    FBases : TObjectDictionary<String, TBase>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddBase(ABase : TBase);
    function GetBase<T: TBase>(AName : String) : T;
    procedure ObservableChanged(Sender : TObject);
  end;

//
// TBase
//
constructor TBase.Create(AName: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FObservers := TList<IObserver>.Create();
  FName := AName;
end;

destructor TBase.Destroy;
begin
  if (FObservers <> nil) then FObservers.Free;
end;

procedure TBase.RegisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
begin
  if (FObservers <> nil) then FObservers.Add(Observer);
end;

procedure TBase.UnregisterObserver(Observer : IObserver);
begin
  if (FObservers <> nil) then FObservers.Remove(Observer);
end;

//
// TGenericBase<T>
//
constructor TGenericBase<T>.Create(AName : String);
begin
  inherited Create(AName);
  FData := Default(T);
end;

constructor TGenericBase<T>.CreateValue(AName : String; AValue : T);
begin
  inherited Create(AName);
  FData := AValue;
end;

//
// TGenericList
//
constructor TGenericList.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBases := TObjectDictionary<String, TBase>.Create([doOwnsValues], 32);
end;

destructor TGenericList.Destroy;
begin
  if (FBases <> nil) then FBases.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TGenericList.AddBase(ABase : TBase);
begin
  FBases.Add(ABase.Name, ABase);
  // Comment out this line and the error doesn't occur.
  ABase.RegisterObserver(Self);
end;

function TGenericList.GetBase<T>(AName : String) : T;
var C : TBase;
begin
  if not FBases.TryGetValue(AName, C) then
    raise Exception.Create('Couldn''t get base.');

  Result := C as T;
end;

procedure TGenericList.ObservableChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
  WriteLn((Sender as TGenericBase).Name);
end;

//
//
//
var C : TGenericBase;
    L : TGenericList;
    K : Integer;
    D : TGenericBase<Double>;
begin
  try
    L := TGenericList.Create;
    try
      for K := 0 to 10 do begin
        C := TGenericBase<Double>.CreateValue(IntToStr(K), K);
        L.AddBase(C);
      end;

      for K := 0 to 10 do begin
        D := L.GetBase<TGenericBase<Double>>(IntToStr(K));
        WriteLn(D.Data);
      end;

    finally
      L.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: If you free L, and L is also used as interface, you are messing with the reference count system for interfaces. This will cause your problem. **Do not mix object and interface references to the same object** unless you really really know what you do. The latter can't be explained in a comment. **Do not free an object that is also used as interface**. The automatic reference count for interfaces will eventually free it, when it is not referenced anymore. Do not interfere with that.

Comment: Wow.  So if I add a my list to an objects Observers list, I can't free it.  If I don't, I have to free it.  Right?  Are you saying that you have to keep track of whether or not something was used as a reference and act accordingly?

Comment: If it is used as an `IObservable`, then no, you shouldn't free it yourself. If it is not used like that, then you can/should. *You could try to declare the interface reference as [weak] or [unsafe], but then it should not be accepted as parameter anymore. Or if it is, things will very likely not work out as expected.*

Comment: You must keep track of whether something is used as **interface reference**, indeed. Read the link at the bottom of my answer to learn more about interfaces in Delphi.

Comment: FWIW, it is safer to do: `ABase.RegisterObserver(Self as IObservable);`.

Comment: Pointless to check nil before calling Free. Free already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you free `L`, and `L` is also in use as interface reference, you are messing with the reference count system for interfaces. This will cause your problem.

In general: **Do not mix object and interface references to the same object unless you really really know what you are doing**. The latter can't be explained in a simple answer.

In short: **Do not free an object that is also used as interface**.

The automatic reference count for interfaces will eventually free it, when it is not referenced anymore. Do not interfere with that. If the item is freed when the reference count is not 0, it will give you the 'Invalid pointer operation' error, as you found out.

More on this in the Delphi documentation: [Using Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Interfaces). This documentation can also be found in the help files.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll read the link.   Not sure I'll use interfaces though!

Comment: @JBM: Oh, but once you know how, they are extremely useful. Not exactly the same as in other languages (because of the refcounts), but all in all, usable in a very similar way. There are just a few caveats, but you'll soon learn about them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the intersection between interfaces and records seems to be empty. This makes it difficult for me to do the kind of programming I want with lots of constant data in records and operator overloading.  I would be nice to make generic mathematical functions (e.g. linear interpolation for records, doubles, integers, numerical integration), but I can't figure out how to do it and still use operator overloading -- I can't constrain the type parameter so that required operators are overloaded (or can't figure it out).

Comment: @JBM: `type myrec<T> = record ... class operator add(const a, b: T): T; ... end;`. Alternatively, use Implicit or Explicit operators to convert. But I don't think your record should be generic. The functions that operate on them should be.

Comment: I don't think that works -- I get an error of "Operator 'Divide' must take least one 'TJBMInterpolatable<T>' type in parameters".  The problem I'm left with is that I can't make myrec<Double> and merec<Vector> (Vector is a record) and write the math generically.  I'd be happy to be wrong, but I don't know see how.  Since I can't constrain the type T to types for which the operators exist (e.g. do myrec<T : Double, Vector>)